# Jetpack Compose rememberSwipeableState saves old state when the list is updated

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, swipe-gesture

I have a list which is showing items by category. If i choose the first category and swipe the first item to the left then change a category to another one. New list is updating but the first item remains as swiped state on new list ui which should display all swipeable items as default state. How can i set default swipe state when category is changed?

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
  fun SwipeRevealDismissItem(
     context: Context,
     itemDataClass: itemDataClass,
     onDelete: (itemDataClass: itemDataClass) -> Unit,
     isEnabled: Boolean,
     defaultState: Int = SwipeState.DEFAULT.value,
     onItemSelected: ((itemDataClass?) -> Unit)? = null,
     content: @Composable () -> Unit
     ) {
         val swipeState = rememberSwipeableState(
             initialValue = defaultState,
         )
         val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight()
        .swipeable(
            state = swipeState,
            anchors = mapOf(
                0f to SwipeState.DEFAULT.value,
                -Utils
                    .dp2px(128, context)
                    .toFloat() to SwipeState.SWIPED.value,
            ),
            thresholds = { _, _ ->
                FractionalThreshold(0.3f)
            },
            orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
            enabled = isEnabled
        )
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
            .width(96.dp)
            .height(108.dp)
            .padding(4.dp)
            .clickable {
//                    onDelete(itemDataClass)
                scope.launch {
                    swipeState.animateTo(0, tween(200, 0))
                }
            },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_delete_white_24dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(16.dp)
                .padding(32.dp),
            tint = colorResource(id = R.color.colorRed),
            contentDescription = null,
        )
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .offset {
            IntOffset(swipeState.offset.value.roundToInt(), 0)
        }
        .clickable {
            onItemSelected?.invoke(itemDataClass)
            if (swipeState.currentValue == SwipeState.SWIPED.value) {
                scope.launch {
                    swipeState.animateTo(SwipeState.DEFAULT.value)
                }
            }
        }
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
}

private enum class SwipeState(val value: Int) {
DEFAULT(0),
SWIPED(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use swipeableState [snapTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/SwipeableState#snapTo(kotlin.Any)) function for resetting state.

```
couroutineScope.launch {
                    swipeableState.snapTo(defaultState)
                }
```